# Duplicate Key issue after lost connection even thou constraint does not exist

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I was doing a migration on laravel for all my DB's (several clients). All DB are the same structure and one of them lost connection and failed before completion. I tried to migrate again and I ran into an issue with a duplicate foreign key.

After looking at the constraints

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE ke where  constraint_name = 'rt_eqmtfixedcycle_excav_id_foreign'
```

[SQL result for schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb6Jm.png)
All other databases successfully inserted 'rt_eqmtfixedcycle_excav_id_foreign' key. But the one that failed 'smv_Forestalleonera' database did not appear, but.

If I try to insert again:

```
use smv_forestalleonera;


alter table `rt_eqmtfixedcycle` add constraint `rt_eqmtfixedcycle_excav_id_foreign`  foreign key (`excav_id`)  references `rt_truck` (`id`) on delete restrict on update cascade
```

I get the following error:

```
12:33:45    alter table `rt_eqmtfixedcycle` 
 add constraint `rt_eqmtfixedcycle_excav_id_foreign` 
 foreign key (`excav_id`) 
 references `rt_truck` (`id`) 
 on delete restrict 
 on update cascade  Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `smv_forestalleonera`.`#sql-7f4d_a8f7` (errno: 121 "Duplicate key on write or update") 0.234 sec
```

I'm using MariaDB 10.2.7.
I've already removed the table and restarted the engine without any results.

(from comment)

```
CREATE TABLE rt_eqmtfixedcycle (
    id smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    excav_id smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, 
    locload_id int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, 
    locdump_id int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, 
    updated_at datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
    updated_by int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, 
    KEY rt_eqmtfixedcycle_id_foreign (id), 
    CONSTRAINT rt_eqmtfixedcycle_id_foreign
        FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES rt_truck (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @Rick James rt_eqmtfixedcycle

    CREATE TABLE rt_eqmtfixedcycle ( 
    id smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    excav_id smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, 
    locload_id int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, 
    locdump_id int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, 
    updated_at datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
    updated_by int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL, 
    KEY rt_eqmtfixedcycle_id_foreign (id), 
    CONSTRAINT rt_eqmtfixedcycle_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (id) 
    REFERENCES rt_truck (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE 
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: Is that any different than 2 days ago?

Comment: Do you already have `smv_forestalleonera` created?

Comment: Yes, i already created the DB.

Comment: What?  No `PRIMARY KEY`?  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE `rt_truck`, too.